# Unable to set text view at the bottom of other text view

Tags: android-layout

[image]I have an ImaveView images and corresponding to each image there is TextView img_name and img_source, I want to align them like 1st image should be placed and at right of image image_name should be displayed and below img_name, img_source should be display.

I have tried with below layout code but couldn't work as expected

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_cover_art"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_favorite"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/star_disabled"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_book_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="Are You My Mother"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_book_author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="Dr. Seuss"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is displaying like

```
Image > TextView > TextView
```

but i require like:

```
Image > TextView
        TextView
```

Also if first TetView is bigger then need to break in another line
Please help.

Comment: Please can you show an image of your layout?

Comment: @Azhy, I have edited question and added the required screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the two textview into another linearview with vertical orientation :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="start"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_cover_art"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_favorite"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_disabled"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>

</FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_book_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="Are You My Mother"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_book_author"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="Dr. Seuss"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I am adding one more Linear Layout tag it is giving me error of Multiple root tags

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it :) what if i want to 1. add some space between each image and 2. break first textview line into multiple lines

Comment: You added the linear layout wrongly, you should put it into the root element, i mean main `LinearLayout` if you do that correctly it's not an error, and if you want to add some space just give all elements some top margin without the first element just add `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` or give it a value in `dimen` resource file to change all of them easily whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks.. I have added LinearLayout inside main LinearLayout and it worked. Can you please let me know how to break the first Text view in multiple line ? I thin by applying manual width right ?

Comment: If you want to break your textview to multiline just write a specific width value and if you want to hide some letters if it was long just write a specific width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Simply place views in Linear Layout after that add `android:orientation="vertical"`

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_book_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Are You My Mother"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_book_author"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Dr. Seuss" />
    </LinearLayout>
```